# Why I am not able to INPUT value in attribute "desc" from my table?

Tags: postgresql

I have simple question why I am not able to simply INPUT value in my table with attribute desc? I want to know this just for inf. I can change in table attribute name any time.

I did what allways INPORT value in attribute but when i came to this name of attribute then i get error. Whith any other name of attribute i don´t have this kind of problem.

```
INSERT INTO table (name, size, desc) VALUES ("problem", "huge", "not able to inport description value");
```

Answer (score 0):

What flavour of SQL are you using? `DESC` is a reserved word in MySQL, Postgres and others. [There is a good list here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words)

`desc` is normally used for ordering results. It is short for descending.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your statement

The SQL statement to create a new row is `INSERT`, not INPUT

`desc` is a reserved keyword, so you need to use double quotes: `"desc"` to refer to the column.

And finally: string constants [need to be enclosed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) in **single** quotes in SQL.

Putting that all together, you need to use:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, size, "desc") 
VALUES ('problem', 'huge', 'not able to inport description value');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn´t realised what i wrote that time so just miss input in "input", I ment INSERT. And this is really helpfull.